# JavaScript Audio API bug in Google Chrome [mobile]

Tags: javascript, api, html5-audio

i created an script that plays an audio file in your browser and analyse the frequency. With this frequency data it creates a graphic based on the data. It works fine in Google Chrome [Desktop] but in the Google Chrome on Android the analyzer.getByteFrequencyData() function returns a Uint8Array but all the data is set to 0. I don't understand why, because its the same code in the same browser. And if i am trying to debug this website with the chrome usb debugging the console show me no errors and the analyzer obj exists.

Here is my code:

```
var player = null;
window.onload = function(){
    player = document.getElementById("audio");
    player.volume = 0.2;
    player.children[0].src = "music.mp3";
    player.load();
    player.addEventListener("canplay", function(){player.play();});

    context = new AudioContext();
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(player); 
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    frameLooper();
}
function frameLooper(){
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < window.innerWidth/3; i++) {
        var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(i*3,0,i*3,window.innerHeight+100);
        grd.addColorStop(0,"#00f");
        grd.addColorStop(1,"#f00");
        ctx.fillStyle = grd;
        ctx.fillRect(i * 3, canvas.height, 2, fbc_array[i] *-2);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://www.nimmi.de/tools/music.html) (This example have additionally an file picker)

Have someone the same problem or is there an mistake in my code ?

Comment: I can confirm the issue still exists in latest Chrome mobile.